# Is it possible to produce confint() in glm faster?

Tags: r, performance, glm, confidence-interval

I want to run an iterative function that runs a glm on many many (i.e. 5000) models, and producing profile likelihood confidence intervals, using `confint()`, takes a little while (~ 3 seconds for each model). Even though I specify that I want `confint()` calculated for only one of my parameters, it still takes this long.

Is there any way to get around this, so that I don't have to take ~3 hours to do this?

Thank you!!

Comment: Sounds like a great candidate for map-reduce and parallelization if the models are independent.

Comment: if you don't mind Wald rather than profile confidence intervals you could try `?confint.default`.